# How to create a remote Git branch without creating a local branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'd like to create a new remote branch for later use.
The most commonly suggested way seems to be:

```
git checkout -b newbranch origin/startingpoint
git push origin newbranch
```

But this will also create the branch locally and put me on it. Is there a way of creating a remote branch without creating it locally and moving onto it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

tl;dr: specify the full destination refname and you can push a commit directly:

```
git push origin origin/startingpoint:refs/heads/newbranch
```

you can push anything that resolves to an id, including just an id:

```
git push origin 6a5343d:refs/heads/newbranch
```

---

The jargon for what `git push` operates on is a "[refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203)", a mapping of source objects to destination names.  If you don't supply a complete refspec, Git fills in defaults from what you did supply.  It's good enough that relatively few people ever even need to know it's happening.

So ["master" generally gets resolved as a branch name](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem) (most people instinctively avoid punning branch and tag names and Git caters to people with those instincts) and you can specify however much of the refname-typing prefix you need to disambiguate; when you say `git push origin newbranch` git resolves the local `newbranch` ref by the linked procedure and then fills in the destination ref for you.

Comment: @twalberg: I'm just guessing but that probably falls out of the idea of pushing "matching" branches.  When the part on the left of the colon is a branch name, git internally adds the `refs/heads/` part.  When you use a raw SHA-1 git can't resolve it against local branches (`refs/heads/*`) and doesn't add the `refs/heads/` bit.  Which could of course be fixed ... who knows! :-)

Answer (score 9):

I would like to make [twalberg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243971/how-to-create-a-remote-git-branch-without-creating-a-local-branch#comment30196959_20244142) an answer. You can create a remote branch by adding `refs/head/` to it:

```
git push origin origin/startingpoint:refs/heads/newbranch
```

As [torek explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243971/how-to-create-a-remote-git-branch-without-creating-a-local-branch#comment30203336_20244142), `git push` adds `refs/heads/` automatically if you have a local branch. If you don't have a local branch, it doesn't know if you want to push to `refs/heads/` or to `refs/tags/`. My version of git says: "we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref". By adding `refs/heads/` you tell git to create a branch on the remote, not a tag.

Comment: Thank you. This distilled and simplified the solution for me.